# Javascript formula port from numbers

Tags: javascript, excel

I am trying to port a formula from numbers (Mac OS 10) to javascript, the original formula is thus:

> (1−(1+(C37÷100)÷C39)^−C45)÷((C37÷100)÷C39)

I have written this:

```
var calcValueOne = (1 - (1 + (yield/100) / coupon_frequency) Math.sqrt() - coupons_until_maturity) / ( (yield/100) / coupon_frequency);
```

where `yield` = C37 and `coupon_frequency` = C39 and `coupons_until_maturity` = C45

I am getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Math'. Expected ')' to end a
>   compound expression.

My mathematics is not to hot and transposing this in to Javascript is proving to be a huge challenge for me, can anyone post a solution to this please?

**EDIT**

@Musa kindly added a response but the number it is returning is not what I expect so I thought I would expand on the values to see if that helps.

`yield (C37) == 9.89`

`coupon_frequency (C39) == 4.00`

`coupons_until_maturity (C45) == 15.00`

The number I am expecting is `12.41` but I am getting `-607.1703544847592` the javascript now looks like this:

`var calcValueOne = (1 - Math.sqrt(1 + (yield/100) / coupon_frequency) - coupons_until_maturity) / ( (yield/100) / coupon_frequency);`

Again for clarity this is the original (excel / numbers) formula:

[image: Original Excel Formula]

Comment: If you want to find the square root of `(1 + (yield/100) / coupon_frequency)` try `Math.sqrt(1 + (yield/100) / coupon_frequency)`

Comment: @Musa thanks for that please see my edit as I am getting an unexpected result returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ^ sign is the exponent function not the square root so use `Math.pow` to calculate it

```js
var yield = 9.89;
var coupon_frequency= 4.00;
var coupons_until_maturity = 15.00
var calcValueOne = (1 - Math.pow((1 + (yield/100) / coupon_frequency), - coupons_until_maturity)) / ( (yield/100) / coupon_frequency);
document.body.innerHTML = calcValueOne;
```